# Customizing time hours in Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using Full Calendar from HTML5Admin, but I need that the calendar show in the rows moments set by me @@periods= ['pre-breakfast', 'post-breakfast', 'pre-lunch', 'post-lunch', 'afternoon', 'pre-dinner', 'post-dinner'] instead to show the time hours in the rows (7am, 8am, 9am, 10am, ....). I don't know if this is possible. I'm using moment.js as well. My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    scrollTime: '07:00:00',
    minTime: '07:00:00',
    maxTime: '22:00:00',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    header:{left:"prev,next,today",
            center:"title",
            right:"month, agendaWeek, agendaDay"},

    // put your options and callbacks here
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible just changing the default properties of the calendar, but you could modify the source code. 
The method in charge of draw the text of the slots , in fullcalendar 2.2.0, is [slatRowHtml](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/dist/fullcalendar.js#L6576):

Specifically this code:

```
axisHtml =
                '<td class="fc-axis fc-time ' + view.widgetContentClass + '" ' + view.axisStyleAttr() + '>' +
                    ((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? // if irregular slot duration, or on the hour, then display the time
                        '<span>' + // for matchCellWidths
                            htmlEscape(calendar.formatDate(slotDate, view.opt('axisFormat'))) +
                        '</span>' :
                        ''
                        ) +
                '</td>';
```

You should add a new statement to verify your ranges and then modify 'axisHtml' to your preferences.

As you can see, slotTime is a moment:

```
var slotTime = moment.duration(+this.minTime); // wish there was .clone() for durations
```

So you can define your owns moment limits and then use the native momentJs comparators:

```
var mySpecificText;
var afternoon = moment(...);
var preLunch = moment(...);
if (slotTime.isBefore(afternoon) && slotTime.isAfter(preLunch){
    mySpecificText = "Pre Lunch";
    axisHtml = '<td class="fc-axis fc-time ' + view.widgetContentClass + '" ' + view.axisStyleAttr() + '><span>' + mySpecificText  + ' </span> </td>'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It's what I guessed. Very usefull.

Comment: You're welcome @DavidDsr. If it was useful, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer :)

Comment: I would like to vote it but it tells me that I need 15 of reputation